# auto number which is text

Tags: number

I have to create a field on opportunity which will be lookup to a custom object. On custom object, there is a Quote Number (Text) which is a standard field, I have to fetch that quote number to a outbound message.

But I do not find the Quote number to define  lookup field filter criteria. Can anyone tell me how to find out that?

Comment: Can you provide some code, or be more specific? I am having trouble understanding what you need.

Comment: Quote Number (Text) if a standard field is most likely API Name `Quote.Name`